# Objective C: Accessing properties of an IBOutlet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iboutlet

If I have a `UIImageView` in an .xib file called `MainViewController` (which, of course, is linked with the respective `MainViewController` interface (.h) and implementation (.m) files), how can I change the image of the `UIImageView` from an entirely separate class?

I want to process all of the image initialisation from a separate class (there are a lot of images), but can't seem to figure out how to do it outside of `MainViewController.m`.

Any tips? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Declare these ImageView as @property and access them in other classes.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *image1;
```

In the implementation class

```
@synthesize image1;
```

Now you can use setter and getter from other classes to access these objects to play around.